# Replace text in an <li>

Tags: jquery, ajax, replace, substr

How can I replace `- undefined` with  or remove it entirely? `substr()` is not a good idea because `'name'` is always changing value. Please help.

```
<li>name - undefined</li>
<li>name - undefined</li>
<li>name - undefined</li>
<li>name - undefined</li>
<li>name - undefined</li>
```

here is my code...

```
 $.each(item.mguest,function(i,item)
 {
    $(".males-list li").first().after('<li class="mlist"><img src="icon/delete.png" title="REMOVE" class="delete-input" style="visibility:hidden;"/>' + item + '</li>')
});
```

Comment: i dont have span, will u please teach me how to replace "undefined", or remove...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.text( function )](https://api.jquery.com/text/#text-function) with `replace()` in a handler function to update the text of the element.

> A function returning the text content to set. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old text value as arguments.

Here is an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').text(function(_, text) {
    return text.replace(' - undefined', ''); //In place of '' use text which you want.
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>name - undefined</li>
  <li>name - undefined</li>
  <li>name - undefined</li>
  <li>name - undefined</li>
  <li>name - undefined</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i update my question, please i dont know how to insert that in my code

Comment: @cristopherevangelista, You are adding `li` dynamically so you can simple use `item.replace(' - undefined', '')` instead of `item`